# evaluation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n e^{-n^2/a} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anybody have an idea, not using the Euler Maclaurin summation formula, for finding
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n e^{-n^2/a} $$

where $1/a$ is suitably small.

I see that $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-n^2/a} $$ can be expressed in terms of a Jacobi theta function, but what about the sum in question?

Comment: The equivalent $a/2$ when $a\to0$ is rather direct, comparing sums to integrals.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that $\theta(z;\tau) = \sum e^{\pi n^2/\tau+2\pi in z}$. Consider $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ on both sides and then substitute $z=0$. 
In this way it is expressed in terms of the Jacobi Theta function.